# Where should I put the inicial data for my CakePHP application?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I'm starting to use the console migrations for CakePHP.

I would like to know where should I put the Initial Data for my application. For example if I'm going to run it in a developer machine for the first time and I need to set up some tables with data.

As I can see in the official book they recommend the "CakeSchema callbacks", but the method "public function after()" inside schema.php is rewritten every time i run:

```
cake schema generate
```

Also this doesn't look like a clean approach.

Where should I put this kind of instruction?

I'm running CakePHP 2.4

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Migrations plugin for such a thing https://github.com/CakeDC/migrations

So that you can provide the migrations (creation of tables, creation of fields, as well insertion of data into your tables)